# How to show a MessageBox with a checkbox?

Tags: c#, checkbox, messagebox

I would like to create a `MessageBox` that has <kbd>Yes</kbd>/<kbd>No</kbd> buttons AND a checkbox.

The application is a picture resizer and it will be re-sizing a number of pictures at once; in the process it will check if the new location filename exists with the option to overwrite it.

The `MessageBox` will give the user the option to overwrite any new files if desired, while the checkbox will prevent having to click <kbd>Yes</kbd> *x* number of times if they want to overwrite every file.

How do I add a checkbox to a `MessageBox` dialog?

Comment: Create a custom dialog.

Comment: Yep, I agree. Custom dialog is the way to go. See here as well: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2fa7e3e3-f55f-4c0d-bcf5-c7278af1d730/how-to-display-a-checkbox-in-message-box

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can't add a checkbox to a MessageBox. As Tim and rsbarro suggest, you should create a custom dialog. Tim's answer will work well, and doesn't require creation of a new class. If you want to design the form in the designer though, you could try this.

- Create a new form with the two buttons and the checkbox you'll need.
- In the forms designer, set the `DialogResult` property of the <kbd>Yes</kbd> button to Yes, and that of the <kbd>No</kbd> button to No. This'll let you discover what button the user clicked.
- Create a property on the form that reflects the state of the checkbox (optional - I don't like to reference a control on one form from another form, but if you make the checkbox public, that'll work too).

```csharp
public bool DoForAll
{
    get { return checkBox.Checked; }
}
```

- On your main form, show the child form when needed. For instance:

```csharp
var options = new Options();
var result = options.ShowDialog();
if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    var doForAll = options.DoForAll;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It was a hard choice between yours and Tim's answer, but yours ended up being a bit easier visually to design.

Comment: The best solution yet!

Answer (score 20):

Create a custom dialog. Here is something that could give you an idea:

```
public static class CheckboxDialog
{   
    public static bool ShowDialog(string text, string caption)
    {
        Form prompt = new Form();
        prompt.Width = 180;
        prompt.Height = 100;
        prompt.Text = caption;
        FlowLayoutPanel panel = new FlowLayoutPanel();
        CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
        chk.Text = text;
        Button ok = new Button() { Text = "Yes" };
        ok.Click += (sender, e) => { prompt.Close(); };
        Button no = new Button() { Text = "No" };
        no.Click += (sender, e) => { prompt.Close(); };
        panel.Controls.Add(chk);
        panel.SetFlowBreak(chk, true);
        panel.Controls.Add(ok);
        panel.Controls.Add(no);
        prompt.Controls.Add(panel);
        prompt.ShowDialog();
        return chk.Checked;
    }
}
```

You can use it in this way:

```
bool overwrite = CheckboxDialog.ShowDialog("overwrite", "Overwrite location?");
```

Comment: What if we have multiple checkboxes? say chk1, chk2, chk3 and want to return the values of the checkboxes which are checked, we can have 2 checkboxes at a time and return both the values. And then how we'll use that? @Tim

Comment: @silent_programmer use Tim's answer as an example, and add more checkboxes in code.

Answer (score 0):

For vb.net (view is this code, only show one buttton)

```
clsMsgBoxV1.ShowDialog("PDF solo de albaranes. (No avisarme mas)", "PDF")
```

and use this shared class:

```
Public Class clsMsgBoxV1

    Shared prompt As Form
    Shared chk As CheckBox
    Public Shared Function ShowDialog(Text As String, caption As String) As Boolean
        'frmUsuario


        prompt = New Form()
        chk = New CheckBox()

        prompt.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent
        prompt.Width = 220
        prompt.Height = 150
        prompt.Text = caption

        prompt.MinimumSize = prompt.Size
        prompt.MaximumSize = prompt.Size

        prompt.MaximizeBox = False
        prompt.MinimizeBox = False

        Dim panel As FlowLayoutPanel =   New FlowLayoutPanel()

        chk.Text = Text
        chk.Width = chk.Width * 2
        chk.Height = 50
        Dim ok As Button = New Button() With {
            .Text = "Leido"
        }
        AddHandler ok.Click, AddressOf OKClick


        'Dim no As Button = New Button() With {
        '.Text = "No"
        '}
        'AddHandler no.Click, AddressOf NoClick


        ok.Width = prompt.Width - 30
        panel.Controls.Add(chk)
        panel.SetFlowBreak(chk, True)
        panel.Controls.Add(ok)
        'panel.Controls.Add(no)
        prompt.Controls.Add(panel)
        prompt.ShowDialog()
        prompt.Dispose()
        Return chk.Checked
    End Function

    Private Shared Sub NoClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        prompt.Close()
    End Sub
    Private Shared Sub OKClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        prompt.Close()

    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a very old thread, but I just wanted to give my two cents.

Ookii is the simplest way to implement a CheckBox into a MessageBox, or customize it: https://github.com/ookii-dialogs/ookii-dialogs-wpf
(I was using it because of the classic "Folder Browser" dialog, so thought might as well use it for the checkbox thing)

Here's my code:

```
using Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf;

//create instance of ookii dialog
TaskDialog dialog = new();

//create instance of buttons
TaskDialogButton butYes = new TaskDialogButton("Yes");
TaskDialogButton butNo = new TaskDialogButton("No");
TaskDialogButton butCancel = new TaskDialogButton("Cancel");

//checkbox 
dialog.VerificationText = "Dont Show Again"; //<--- this is what you want.

//customize the window
dialog.WindowTitle = "Confirm Action";
dialog.Content = "You sure you want to close?";
dialog.MainIcon = TaskDialogIcon.Warning;

//add buttons to the window
dialog.Buttons.Add(butYes);
dialog.Buttons.Add(butNo);
dialog.Buttons.Add(butCancel);

//show window
TaskDialogButton result = dialog.ShowDialog(this);

//get checkbox result
if (dialog.IsVerificationChecked)
{
    //do stuff
}

//get window result
if (result != butYes)
{
    //if user didn't click "Yes", then cancel the closing.
    e.Cancel = true;
    return;
}
```