# having a check box in message box

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

in a message box there are 2 buttons, `Yes` and `No`. I want to have checkbox inside of message box which says `Do it for all items` , So if the button `yes` is selected , that is true for all items and if `no` is selected , that is true for all items.

Is it possible in messagebox?

Comment: _Is it possible in messagebox?_ Did you try anything?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17385895/how-to-show-a-messagebox-with-a-checkbox

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is no. You cannot create a messagebox with a checkbox. You would have to create a custom dialog box. You need to create a form that looks the way you wish it to look and use the ShowDialog() method to display the form. This will display a modal dialog box in your application. The code after the ShowDialog method is not executed until the dialog box is closed.

```
using (Form2 frm = new Form2())
            {
                frm.ShowDialog();
                if (frm.DialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
                {

                }
                else if (frm.DialogResult == DialogResult.No)
                {

                }
            }
```

On clicking yes or no from within the dialog box, you would do the following to close the dialog box with a DialogResult

```
  private void btnYes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult = DialogResult.Yes;
        }

  private void btnNo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult = DialogResult.No;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you , but it seems you didn't read my question

Comment: The answer to your question is no. You cannot create a messagebox with a checkbox. You would have to create a custom dialog box.